# angular 4: *ngIf with multiple conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular-ng-if

I'm confused a bit. I need to hide block if result have one of several cases. But seems it not working correctly...

```
<div *ngIf="currentStatus !== 'open' || currentStatus !== 'reopen' ">

    <p padding text-center class="text-notification">{{message}}</p>

</div>
```

It's just appeared with other condition. It doesn't work neither 1 condition nor for 2. Also tried `*ngIf="currentStatus !== ('open' ||  'reopen') "` but it's works ok only for 1 case.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? When should it evaluate to `true` and when should it evaluate to `false`?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Besides the redundant `)` this expression will always be `true` because `currentStatus` will always match one of these two conditions:

```
currentStatus !== 'open' || currentStatus !== 'reopen'
```

perhaps you mean one of

```
!(currentStatus === 'open' || currentStatus === 'reopen')
(currentStatus !== 'open' && currentStatus !== 'reopen')
```

Comment: So what is the expected behavior depending on what status?

Comment: @Merge-pony It seems that you use OR instead of AND, because `!(currentStatus === 'open' || currentStatus === 'reopen')` gives the same result as `currentStatus !== 'open' && currentStatus !== 'reopen'`

Comment: @mankers yes, it is!!! But it doesn't work. I'm using Ionic 3 and Angular 4 stack...

Answer (score 23):

You got a ninja ')'.

Try :

```
<div *ngIf="currentStatus !== 'open' || currentStatus !== 'reopen'">
```

Comment: made mistake in example. my bad. in original code result as asked