# How ngIf can validate multiple conditions in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-ng-if

Could you please guide me how to use `*ngIf` in Angular 9 for multiple conditions as shown below. The following is not working for me.

```html
*ngIf="abc !! xyz"
```

However, it is working for an individual condition like

```html
*ngIf="abc"
```

or

```html
*ngIf="xyz"
```

and the TS code is:

```js
radioButtonChanged($event){
   let radioValue = event.target['value'];

   console.log(radioValue);
   if(radioValue =='abc'){
     this.abc = true;
     this.xyz = false;
   } else{
     this.abc=false;
     this.xyz = true;
   }      
}
```

Comment: `*ngIf="abc || xyz"`

Comment: use a function for a more complex condition.

Comment: @HDJEMAI: Binding a function to a directive will trigger it for each change detection cycle in case of default CD strategy. It isn't recommended.

Comment: Some times when changes are not detected, it cannot be helpful ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 4: \*ngIf with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801823/angular-4-ngif-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Let me add my ts code for more clarity

Comment: @HDJEMAI; That didnt work

Comment: I am trying to achieve to show 3 html elements based on radio button selection. Based on radio button selection I can able to display elements without any issues. However, I want to display a common html element based on any selection.

Comment: some times you may need to trigger change detection manually, you may also make form touched, in some specific cases it helps, consider providing a `stackblitz` demo to show your issue.

Comment: It is resolved now. I took one more variable for defining common fields. 3 variables for ex ; abc, xyz, pqr

Answer (score 0):

You can use if-else concept here:

```
<div *ngIf="condition1; else condition2"></div>

<ng-template #condition2>
  <div> whatever </div>
</ng-template>
```

The way you are using it; the `||` operator will work as a binary operator like `&&` .That is not the correct way of doing it.

METHOD 2:

You can check all the conditions you want in the component.ts file and then assign the result of your conditions to a variable and bind it with `*ngIf`.

This will be kind of tedious but the HTML will remain clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
// If you want both the conditions to be true 
<div *ngIf="abc && xyz"> whatever </div>

// If you want either of them to be true
<div *ngIf="abc || xyz"> whatever </div>

// If you want neither of them to be true
<div *ngIf="!abc && !xyz"> whatever </div>
```